# How get the distinct value of calls of distinct ID list?

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have the following Problem: assume I have the following table loaded in QlikView:

[image: Table in Qlikview]

Now I want to calculate the number of distinct ids, "calls over 60 sec" and the number of distinct "calls from other over 60 sec", if "calls over 60 sec" is 0.

Using `For count(distinct(if([calls over 60 sec]>0, ID)))` I get = 2, which is correct.

Now `for count(distinct(if([calls over 60 sec]=0 and [calls from other over 60 sec]>0, ID)))` I get 3.

But the answer I am looking for is 1. Because overall months only 1 id is called by other.

Or do I need Set expression? Basically, I what  for the chosen month to calculate the distinct number of ids as well as the conditions above.

I am grateful for every answer.

Comment: " Because overall months only 1 id is called by other." so you want to aggregate by month? but what kind of aggregation (sum,avg,max,min...)?

Comment: Yes I want to do a aggr by month. I have a monty excel list, with this structure above. The  IDs may vary over month. So if i choose month 6,7,8 in qlik i want a distinct list of ids and based on this list calls over 60 sec etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
COUNT ( DISTINCT { < [calls over 60 sec]={"0"} , [calls from other over 60 sec] = { ">0" }  > }  ID)
```

And aggr:

```
// SUM ( // sometimes

Aggr (
COUNT ( DISTINCT { < [calls over 60 sec]={"0"} , [calls from other over 60 sec] = { ">0" }  > }  ID)
, year, month
)

// )
```

And, pls, don't use "IF" in formulas

Comment: I tried the code. It works if I choose 1 month. But as soon as i select more months it starts double counting.